# How to store the values of the output of a loop in an array in shell scripting?

Tags: arrays, shell, scripting

In shell scripting, I have a loop with an `if` condition inside a `for` loop.

```
for ((init; condition; increment))
do
    if ((condition)) then
        printf ...
    fi
done
```

`printf` statement prints the values on the output. However, I want to store these values in an array to use inside another loop. How do I do this?

Comment: Joker, please be more attentive to the language being used before editing the syntax. Your changes were perfectly valid for C#, not so for Unix shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize an array before `for loop` and inside `for loop` just keep appending to array.

Code skeleton:

```
# initializing an array
arr=()
for ((i=0; i<=5; i++ )) do if ((...)) then arr+=($i); printf .... fi done
```

- `arr=()` creates a new array
- `arr+=($i)` appends/adds an element into array `arr`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=() #declare an array outside the scope of loop
idx=0   #initialize a counter to zero
for i in {53..99} #some random number range
do
    data[idx]=`printf "number=%s\n" $i` #store data in array
    idx=$((idx+1)) #increment the counter
done
echo ${data[*]} #your result
```

**What code does**

- creates and empty array
- creates an index-counter for array
- stores result of output printf command in array at corresponding index (the backquote tells interpreter to do that)